# Map.Entry::getKey is throwing error under groupby

Tags: java, java-8

`Map.Entry::getKey` is throwing error for the below code

```
Map<String,List <String> > bikes= new HashMap<>();

bikes.put("ROBBIN",Arrays.asList("FZ","APACHE","HONDA"));
bikes.put("VIN",Arrays.asList("FZ","HONDA"));
bikes.put("GRACE",Arrays.asList("APACHE","HONDA"));
bikes.put("RUBBY",Arrays.asList("FZ","BUS","HONDA"));


Map<String, List<String>> group1;
bikes.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(x->x.getValue().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                     Function.identity(), 
                     Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                        Collectors.toList())
                ));
```

Comment: I believe the code won't even compile.  You should observe a compilation error instead seeing a error being thrown (which implies an exception happened in runtime).

Comment: Add expected output please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flatMap(x->x.getValue().stream())` converts your `Stream<Map.Entry<String,List <String>>>` to a `Stream<String>`, so you don't have `Map.Entry`s anymore.

It looks like you want to invert the input `Map` (i.e. make the `List` elements of the values of the input `Map` the keys of the output `Map`).

This can be done as follows:

```
Map<String, List<String>> group1 =
    bikes.entrySet()
         .stream().flatMap(e->e.getValue()
                               .stream()
                               .map(v->new SimpleEntry<String,String>(v,e.getKey())))
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                           Collectors.toList())));
```

Now `flatMap` transforms each `Map.Entry<String,List<String>>` to multiple `Map.Entry<String,String>` instances, each comprised of a key which is a value of the `List<String>` and a value which is the key of the original `Map.Entry`.

This will result in the following `Map`:

```
{BUS=[RUBBY], FZ=[ROBBIN, VIN, RUBBY], APACHE=[GRACE, ROBBIN], HONDA=[GRACE, ROBBIN, VIN, RUBBY]}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to traverse this map, you could do following statement:

```
Map<String, List<String>> bikeOwners =
        bikes.entrySet()
             .stream().flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().map(bike -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(bike, entry.getKey())))
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

---

**Output:**

```
{
    "BUS" : [ "RUBBY" ],
    "FZ" : [ "ROBBIN", "VIN", "RUBBY" ],
    "APACHE" : [ "GRACE", "ROBBIN" ],
    "HONDA" : [ "GRACE", "ROBBIN", "VIN", "RUBBY"]
}
```